# R Programming: Extract Previous Column Value based on Condition

Tags: r

The dataframe is as below. I have a dataset with 50+ variables, all labeled Var_1 .. Var_50. One of the 50 variables has country code (UK or US). The data frame is structured such that if var_5 = "UK", then var_4 always contains the store number.

The code I want to write is - If var_5 = UK, then country = "var_5" and store="var_4". If I can setup a loop so I don't have to copy-paste this 50 times it would be great!

```
ID  Brand    Var_1       Var_2      Var_3     Var_4       Var_5
1   Soaps    Supervisor  Quantity   StoreK    UK          Owner
2   Shampoo  StoreZ      US         
3   Oil      Material    StoreY     UK        Supplier
```

What I want is below data frame

```
ID  Brand    Var_1       Var_2      Var_3     Var_4    Country    StoreID
1   Soaps    Supervisor  Quantity   StoreK    UK       UK         StoreK 
2   Shampoo  StoreZ      US                            US         StoreZ
3   Oil      Material    StoreY     UK                 UK         StoreY
```

Hope this clarifies my question.

Comment: Please format your dataset.  It is not clear where your column ends and new column begins.  Use `dput` to show the example along with expected output

Answer (score 0):

Since the column containing country and store information is already there, there is no need to create additional columns, just rename them.

```
the.data <- data.frame(Brand = c("Soap", "Oil", "Mail"),  var1 = rnorm(3), var2 = c("store_K", "store_xs", "store_k"), var3 = c("UK", "AL", "USA"))
# subset your data frame and select rows that are UK or US
uk.data <- the.data[grep("UK|US", the.data$var3), ]
# rename the columns
colnames(uk.data)[3:4]<- c("Store", "Country")
```

Comment: ID  Brand    var_1            Var_2            Var_3            var_4
1   Soaps    Supervisor   Quantity     StoreK   UK
2   Shampoo  StoreZ   US      
3   Oil          Material     StoreY   UK

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
data <-    data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3), Brand = c("Soaps", "Shampoo", "Oil"), 
                      Var_1 = c("Supervisor", "Storez", "Material"), 
                      Var_2 = c("Quantity", "US", "StoreY"),
                      Var_3 = c("StoreK", "", "UK"),
                      Var_4 = c("UK", "", ""))


tmp <- data.frame(t(apply(data, 1, function(x) { pos = grep("UK|US", x)
                                                 if (length(pos)) {c(x[pos], x[pos - 1])} 
                                                 else { c("", "") }   
                                                 })))

names(tmp) <- c("Country", "Store")
data <- cbind(data, tmp)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It gives me below error.

Comment: error: Warning message:
In `[.data.table`(out, , `:=`(c("Country", "Store"), as.data.table(tmp))) :
  Supplied 2 columns to be assigned a list (length 12992) of values (12990 unused)

Comment: Hi sri, try it out now !

Comment: Hi User2321, thanks but it still gives me the same error. Could it be because I have setup my "data" as a dataframe? I understand your logic of picking up position where UK/US occur and extracting that column and previous one, so thanks!

Comment: I think it most certainly is to do with dataframe, as when I checked the typeof(data) it says list, and when I convert that to a data frame to run the above steps, it does not work. Alas, when I try converting my dataframe to a list, it still does not work :)

Comment: Sri I have updated the solution to not include any data table commands. If you still have an issue please let me know